# "We all" or "all we"?

Tags: phrase-usage, word-order, plural-forms

I'm bit confused with the following two sentences. Which is the correct usage?

> It's an important point that all we need to understand.

or

> It's an important point that we all need to understand.

Comment: Isn't it better? *It's an imp. point that all of us need to understand.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"It's an important point that we all need to understand" is fine and grammatical (your second option). It is synonymous with "it's an important point that all of us need to understand." Both are fine and there's no reason to prefer one to the other.

The first sentence is not grammatical. The word "all," before pronouns, always takes "of [object pronoun]". So "all of us, all of them, all of you." (It's grammatically correct, but semantically strange, to say "all of me, all of her, all of him.")

Comment: "Which bit of you got wet when that car drove through the puddle right next to you?"  - "All of me."

Comment: "All" before pronouns doesn't always take of + object pronoun. The sentence  " All I remember is his first name" is grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

The word *all* is a Determinative (WORD CLASS). One main difference between a noun and a pronoun is that a noun can take a determinative at it's head, but a pronoun can't. And hence the following sentence is incorrect -

> It's an important point that all we need to understand. [INCORRECT]

There is however a Compound-Pronoun - *we all* - that means the same thing as *"all of us"*.

> It's an important point that we all need to understand. [CORRECT]

Notice that in the last sentence that *all* is not a determinative, it's part of a Compound-Pronoun.